# Does VSCode have shortcut for closing current tag, which is "alt + . " in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I guess in Sublime Text 3, when you use "alt + .<period> ", at "shortcut here" below, closing tag </ul> is put automatically.
Does VSCode have the shortcut for same function?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
//shortcut here
```

The Extension "Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer" is already installed for VSCode.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn on `Auto Closing Tags`?

Navigate to your settings in VSCode, type in *close last opened* and under extensions, click `HTML` and you can enable/disable autoclosing of `HTML` tags. By doing this, once you've typed in the first tag and you press enter, it automatically adds the closing tag.[image]

Comment: To create new tag in VSCode, I don't have any problem, as you show me, it automatically adds the closing tag. But sometimes I copy some code from anoher documents and forget to copy closing tag.. I wonder if it has shortcut for that.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I will look and see if I can find something for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think VSCode doesn't have this feature built in. This extension can be used as the `Close Tag` function in Sublime Text 3:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Compulim.compulim-vscode-closetag

The default shortcut is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The extension that does it just like in Sublime is called `Close HTML/XML tag`

> **Usage:**
>
> By default, close tag is bound to Alt+.

[image]